# OData DELETE request conflicts with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, odata, wcf-data-services

I have an MVC4 web webapplication running on my server and I have a ADO.NET Data Service (OData) service in the same directory.

Everything is working fine, my views can consume my OData service from client-side, but all the DELETE requests are failing with Error 500:

```
 Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The view 'Northwind.svc/Products(90)' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Northwind.svc/Products(90).aspx
~/Views/Home/Northwind.svc/Products(90).ascx
~/Views/Shared/Northwind.svc/Products(90).aspx
~/Views/Shared/Northwind.svc/Products(90).ascx
~/Views/Home/Northwind.svc/Products(90).cshtml
~/Views/Home/Northwind.svc/Products(90).vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Northwind.svc/Products(90).cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Northwind.svc/Products(90).vbhtml
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The request:

```
Request URL:http://{myhost}/Northwind.svc/Products(90)
Request Method:DELETE
Accept:application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,hu;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host: {myhost}
MaxDataServiceVersion:2.0
Origin:http://{myhost}
```

Did anybody experience the same issue? I appreciate all the ideas.

Comment: Check that delete is enabled in the DataService Initialize function i.e. SetEntitySetAccessRule("Products", EntitySetRights.All);

Comment: Thanks, but the service allows all operations: config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);